# Regex: Replace string with a +

Tags: regex

I have the following text,

```
whatsapp:2349012367748
```

I'd like to strip the **whatsapp:** part from the text and replace it with a +

Desired result will be `+2349012367748`

How can I achieve this with a regex expression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Matching* and *replacing* are different issues. "Regex" can't "replace" anything - all it does is *match*.

To match `whatsapp:` simply use that text with an anchor to start:

```
^whatsapp:
```

To replace it, you need to use a tool/language. Syntax varies, you'll need to specify the search as `^whatsapp:` and the replacement as `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \bwhatsapp:(?=\d+)
Replace: +
```

If you want to instead enforce that the phone number have a certain number of digits, say 8 to 15, then use:

```
\bwhatsapp:\d{8,15}
```